# Excel to google search

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, full-text-search

I am currently using the formula below in VBA to search the web using the criteria in the excel sheet. My question is how do I have the link to paste in the worksheet. I don't want to go to the website, I want a hyperlink. What is the code I need to have the search link past in the worksheet?

```
Sub GoogleSearch()

Dim objIEBrowser

Set objIEBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objIEBrowser.Visible = True

Dim SearchTerm As String

For Each cell In Range("f:f")

    SearchTerm = cell
    SearchTerm = Replace(SearchTerm, " ", "+")

    objIEBrowser.navigate "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & SearchTerm

Next

End
```

Comment: what is in the cell value that you are searching?

Comment: I want to search all rows in column F

Comment: assuming you wanna search for apple, which link are you trying to return to cell?

Comment: I have the criteria in column F that I want to search. I want the link to return to column g. Have over 24,000 rows that I need this macro to pull links for. I have a Lenovo laptop

Comment: okay again, when you search google you will get 100's of links so which one

Comment: More than 100 windows open for column F